# python library dependency error :pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound: pycups

Tags: python, linux, dependencies, cups, google-cloud-print

I want to install this repo https://github.com/armooo/cloudprint on my raspberry pi. 
The instruction is here
https://baxeico.wordpress.com/2014/06/03/raspberry-pi-google-cloud-print/

I have

```
sudo apt-get install cups
sudo apt-get install python-daemon python-cups
sudo dpkg -i cloudprint*.deb
sudo service cloudprintd login
```

Then i got the error message shown here:

> pi@raspberrypi ~ $ sudo service cloudprintd login Traceback (most
>   recent call last):   File "/usr/sbin/cloudprintd", line 5, in 
>       from pkg_resources import load_entry_point   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 2707, in
>   
>       working_set.require(**requires**)   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 686, in
>   require
>       needed = self.resolve(parse_requirements(requirements))   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 584, in
>   resolve
>       raise DistributionNotFound(req) pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound: pycups

I tried to fix this by:

```
sudo apt-get install libcups2-dev
```

But nothing seems to work. Any help will be appreciated!

I have tried pip install pycups and I have an error message like this:

> building 'cups' extension
>
> gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall
>   -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -DVERSION="1.9.73" -I/usr/include/python2.7 -c cupsmodule.c -o build/temp.linux-armv7l-2.7/cupsmodule.o
>
> cupsmodule.c:22:20: fatal error: Python.h: No such file or directory
>
> compilation terminated.
>
> error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1

Comment: have you tried `pip install pycups`?

Comment: @wgwz I did. it gave me another error.

Comment: `apt-get install python-dev` and then try `pip install pycups` again..

Comment: @wgwz thanks it is good

Answer (score 1):

As a general rule of thumb if you see an error like:

```
fatal error: Something.h: No such file or directory
```

It usually means you are missing a `something-dev` package from the repositories.

In this case `apt-get install python-dev` was the dependency for `pycups` (a Python package)

And once you get `pycups` cloudprint should work.